# Satisfying the following determinant inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, normed-spaces

I would like to find **least restrictive conditions** on $W = W^T \succ 0, \ V = V^T \succ 0$ (which are $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ positive definite matrices) such that the following inequality is satisfied:

$$ \text{det} \bigg( W^{-1} \Gamma W^{-1} + A^T V A \bigg) \geq 1  \tag{*}  $$

where $\Gamma = \Gamma^T \triangleq W - B P B^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $, but is not necessarily a positive definite matrix, with $P = P^T \succ 0$ being a $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ positive definite matrix. Further, the matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are arbitrary.

I was hoping that (*) can be simplified by using appropriate determinant inequalities, for example using Minkowski's determinant inequality (here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251646/reverse-minkowski-and-related-determinant-inequalities), but this requires that $\Gamma$ be positive definite--though it is symmetric $\Gamma = \Gamma^T$--so not sure. Further, the second term would need to be positive definite as well. I would not want to impose conditions on $A,B$ though.

Comment: You should edit your questions, not [delete them](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2375546/339790).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo hello -- was wondering if you had any suggestions on how to move fwd with this? been pretty stuck with this :( would appreciate any help. thank you!

Comment: This is the third variant you've posted? You've got to stop that, or you're going to get your privileges revoked. Some questions are intractable, or not of general interest. I've already told you that.

Comment: @TedShifrin Hi -- I just presented the problem from before in a succinct manner so that it would be easy to read. With all due respect, I think it is an interesting problem for people interested in linear algebra, as the question got some upvotes once it was highlighted after I put a bounty on it. So, hopefully someone comes to my rescue. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 2):

I have listed some observations below.
What you want appears to be impossible without restricting $A$ and $B$ heavily.

**First observation:**
If $n$ is odd, there are no positive definite matrices $W,V,P$ so that (*) holds for all $A,B$.
Consider $W,V,P,A$ fixed and let $B=tI$ for $t\in\mathbb R$.
Then the matrix whose determinant you are interested in is
$$
X-t^2Y,
$$
where $Y=W^{-1}PW^{-1}$ and $X=W^{-1}+A^TVA$.
Notice that $X$ and $Y$ are independent of $t$.
When $t$ is large, the term $-t^2Y$ dominates, and you can essentially forget $X$.
More rigorously<sup>1</sup>,
$$
\det(X-t^2Y)
=
\det(-t^2Y)+O(t^{2n-2})
=
(-1)^nt^{2n}\det(Y)+O(t^{2n-2}).
$$
Notice that $\det(Y)=\det(P)\det(W)^{-2}>0$.
The exact form of the error term is irrelevant; it's enough that it's $O(t^{2n-2})$ so that it grows slower than the first term.
In fact, $t\mapsto\det(X-t^2Y)$ is a polynomial, and the sign of a polynomial for large argument only depends on the leading term.

What all this means is that if $n$ is odd, then the determinant will be negative for large enough $t$.
In particular, it cannot be at least 1 for all $t$.

It was not important that $B$ is a multiple of the identity.
The same argument goes through for $B=tC$ for any invertible $C$; you would just have $Y=W^{-1}BPB^TW^{-1}$ which has positive determinant.
The conclusion is: The desired identity cannot hold for all $B$ if $n$ is odd, no matter what you do.
(To prove that something doesn't hold for all $B$, it's enough to find one counterexample. I chose the simplest one, but there are many more.)

**Second observation:**
If $A=B=0$, then your (*) becomes $\det(W)\leq1$.
This is a necessary assumption to make on $W$.
I don't know if it's sufficient in even dimensions.

**Third observation:**
The determinant is independent of basis.
You can use this freedom to diagonalize one of your symmetric matrices.

**Fourth observation:**
Any positive definite matrix has a well defined positive definite square root.
(To find it: diagonalize and take the root of each diagonal element.)
There is a symmetric matrix $W^{-1/2}\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ which is positive definite and whose square is $W^{-1}$.
Similarly, there is a symmetric $P^{-1/2}$.
Now choose $B=W^{-1/2}P^{-1/2}$.
The transpose is $B^T=P^{-1/2}W^{-1/2}$.
Then it happens that
$$
\Gamma
=
W-W^{-1/2}P^{-1/2}PP^{-1/2}W^{-1/2}
=
W-W^{-1/2}IW^{-1/2}
=
0.
$$
Now if you also choose $A=0$, then $W^{-1} \Gamma W^{-1} + A^T V A=0$ and (*) fails.
This works for any positive definite $W,V,P$.

**Fifth observation:**
If you are willing to restrict $A$ and $B$, there is a way.
Starting with observation 2, assume $\det(W)<1$.
Let $Z=A^TVA-W^{-1}BPB^TW^{-1}$.
We have $\det(W^{-1}+Z)=\det(W)^{-1}\det(I+WZ)$.

Denote by $\|Q\|_\infty$ the largest absolute value of the elements of a matrix, and by $\|Q\|$ the operator norm.
Suppose $\|Q\|_\infty\leq1$.
Using the polynomial formula
$$
\det(Q)= \sum_\sigma \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^{n} Q_{\sigma(i),i}
$$
for a determinant, one can see that
$$
\begin{split}
&
|\det(I+Q)-1|
\\&=
\left|
\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+Q_{i,i})-1
+
\sum_{\sigma\neq\text{id}} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^{n} (\delta_{\sigma(i),i}+Q_{\sigma(i),i})
\right|
\\&\leq
\left|
\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+Q_{i,i})-1
\right|
+
\sum_{\sigma\neq\text{id}}
\left|
\prod_{i=1}^{n} (\delta_{\sigma(i),i}+Q_{\sigma(i),i})
\right|
\\&\leq
(2^n-1)\times\|Q\|_\infty
+
(n!-1)\times 2^{n-1}\|Q\|_\infty
\\&\leq
2^nn!\|Q\|_\infty.
\end{split}
$$
Each term in the product $\left|
\prod_{i=1}^{n} (\delta_{\sigma(i),i}+Q_{\sigma(i),i})
\right|$ above is at most $2$ in absolute value, and there is at least one $i$ so that $\delta_{\sigma(i),i}=0$, so the product is at most $2^{n-1}\|Q\|_\infty$ in absolute value.
The rest of the estimates are similar.

If $A$ and $B$ are such that $\|Z\|<\epsilon$, then $\|WZ\|_\infty\leq\|WZ\|\leq\|W\|\|Z\|<\epsilon\|W\|$, and so
$$
\begin{split}
\det(W^{-1}+Z)
&=
\det(W)^{-1}\det(I+WZ)
\\&=
\det(W)^{-1}
-
\det(W)^{-1}(\det(I+WZ)-1)
\\&\geq
\det(W)^{-1}
-
\det(W)^{-1}2^nn!\|WZ\|_\infty
\\&\geq
\det(W)^{-1}
-
2^nn!\|W\|\epsilon\det(W)^{-1}.
\end{split}
$$
Now if $\epsilon\leq\frac{1-\det(W)}{2^nn!\|W\|}$, then $\det(W)^{-1}
-
2^nn!\|W\|\epsilon\det(W)^{-1}\geq1$
and so (*) holds.

To get $\|Z\|<\epsilon$, it is enough that $\|A\|<\sqrt{\epsilon/2\|V\|}$ and $\|B\|<\|W^{-1}\|^{-1}\sqrt{\epsilon/2\|P\|}$; the estimate leading to this is immediate from the formula for $Z$.
This leads to explicit restrictions on $A$ and $B$.
Using the $\epsilon$ from above, we get
$$
\|A\|<\min\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\det(W)}{2^{n+1}n!\|W\|\|V\|}},\sqrt{1/2\|V\|}\right)
$$
and
$$
\|B\|<\min\left(\|W^{-1}\|^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1-\det(W)}{2^{n+1}n!\|W\|\|P\|}},\|W^{-1}\|^{-1}\sqrt{1/2\|P\|}\right).
$$
(I also made the assumption $\epsilon\leq1$ to simplify some calculations.)

If you need more details on this observation, please ask a separate question; it would be sidetrack here to go into all details, since your original question wanted no restrictions on $A$ and $B$.

---

<sup>1</sup>
The second inequality is nothing more than $\det(\lambda A)=\lambda^n\det(A)$.
The first one is a little harder to see.
One option is to rewrite it as
$$
\det(X-t^2P)
=
\det((P^{-1}X-t^2I)P)
=
\det(P^{-1}X-t^2I)\det(P).
$$
Now it's clear that it's a characteristic polynomial (with $t^2$ instead of $\lambda$) times $\det(P)$.
The leading order term of $\det(Q-\lambda I)$ is $(-\lambda)^n$, and it is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $\lambda$.
Substitute $\lambda=t^2$ to get the result I used above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Is the $t$ going to be made up of $W^{-1},B,B^T$? Any closed form for this? I see that you are grouping all the positive stuff into $X$ and keeping the negative term appearing in $\Gamma$ into $t$. But, is it really the case that your matrix $X$ would be positive definite for any $A,B$ to make the determinant equality you have? Can that error term not be negative and so violate the determinant inequality? Also, I appreciate the odd part, but I don't see how you get $(-1)^n t^{2n}$ -- would appreciate any further clarification on this.

Comment: @user2457324 I added an intermediate step to the determinant calculation. It's all about how multiplying a matrix with a scalar effects the determinant. // The matrix $X$ can be anything at all, and the asymptotic behaviour is the same. // Finding an explicit formula for a sufficiently large $t$ seems irrelevant to me. The biggest term is something negative times $t^{2n}$, and the biggest term will determine the sign for large $t$. This is true for any polynomial. The determinant is a polynomial of $t$. If you want an explicit $t$ for some reason, I can look into it tomorrow.

Comment: @user2457324 I added many more details. Unfortunately, the property you desire appears to be impossible.

Comment: @user2457324 Observation 4 says that whenever $W$ and $P$ are positive definite (and $V$ is anything), there will be $A$ and $B$ so that the matrix of interest is zero and therefore has zero determinant. You will have to assume at least (and this is probably not enough!) that $W$ or $P$ has a zero eigenvalue. You will be able to do something if you restrict $A$ and $B$ heavily, but you told you didn't want to do that. I would say that **there are no suitable conditions that satisfy your needs**, and that's it. It seems that whatever you are trying to achieve, this is not a viable approach.

Comment: @user2457324 I gave some conditions on $A,B$. If you need more details, do ask a new question. You can link here to provide context.

Comment: @user2457324 The "it is enough" part comes from $\|Z\|=\|A^TVA-W^{-1}BPB^TW^{-1}\|\leq\|A^TVA\|+\|W^{-1}BPB^TW^{-1}\|\leq\|A\|^2\|V\|+\|W^{-1}\|^2\|B\|^2\|P\|<\epsilon/2+\epsilon/2=\epsilon$. The minimum corresponds to my wanting to assume $\|Z\|<\min(\epsilon,1)$. It's for convenience. You can survive without it, but I didn't want to figure out the details. And +1 for the follow-up; I hope someone can help.

Comment: @user2457324 Thanks! If you replace $\min(\epsilon,1)$ with $\epsilon$, you'll have to redo the estimate for $|\det(I+Q)-1|$. The polynomial formula holds for any $Q$. The idea is simply that (*) holds for $A=B=0$ and therefore for small $A,B$. The calculation just quantifies that smallness. My conditions are not optimal. I can't say much more. I will stop replying to comments now; keep asking more questions to learn the concepts. It takes time and effort to build intuition.

Comment: @user2457324 The assumption $\text{det} (W) \leq 1$ has nothing to do with $\epsilon$. The second observation doesn't depend on the fourth one.

Comment: Can you please take a look at your step: $\det(W)^{-1} \det(I+WZ) = \det(W)^{-1} {\color{red} {-}} \det(W)^{-1} ( \det(I+WZ) - 1)$ should the minus not be a plus instead, i.e., $\det(W)^{-1} {\color{red} {+}} \det(W)^{-1} ( \det(I+WZ) - 1)$? Maybe I am not seeing something right?

Comment: @user2457324 For further information, please ask separate questions. This comment thread is way too long already.