# On the polynomial formula for determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, determinant

I have three questions:

1) For the determinant of a matrix $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, there is the following polynomial formula:
$$
\det(Q)= \sum_\sigma \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^{n} Q_{\sigma(i),i}
\tag{*} $$
I know about the characteristic polynomial of a matrix whose roots are the eigenvalues, but I am not sure about how (*) comes about? In particular, what is $\sigma$ here and is $Q_{\sigma(i),i}$ the element at the $\sigma(i)$-th row and $i$-th column of $Q$? Would $\text{sgn}(\sigma) $ ever be negative?

2) As a follow up, let $\|Q\|_\infty$ be the largest absolute value of the elements of the $Q$ matrix, and let $\|Q\|$ be the operator norm, then, applying (*) to the below, we have
$$
\begin{split}
&
|\det(I+Q)-1|
\\&=
\left|
\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+Q_{i,i})-1
+
\sum_{\sigma\neq\text{id}} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^{n} (\delta_{\sigma(i),i}+Q_{\sigma(i),i})
\right|
\\ 
\end{split}
\tag{**}
$$

Can someone please explain how each of the two terms come about in (**)? I believe that the first term captures the diagonal components of $Q$ and the second term are the off-diagonals? Not sure what the $\delta_{\sigma(i), i}$ means though.

3) Finally, I would like to find **a better** upper bound for $(**)$ than the one given by @JoonasIlmavirta as

\begin{split}
&
|\det(I+Q)-1|
\\&=
\left|
\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+Q_{i,i})-1
+
\sum_{\sigma\neq\text{id}} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^{n} (\delta_{\sigma(i),i}+Q_{\sigma(i),i})
\right|
\\&\leq
\left|
\prod_{i=1}^{n} (1+Q_{i,i})-1
\right|
+
\sum_{\sigma\neq\text{id}}
\left|
\prod_{i=1}^{n} (\delta_{\sigma(i),i}+Q_{\sigma(i),i})
\right|
\\&\leq
(2^n-1)\times\|Q\|_\infty
+
(n!-1)\times 2^{n-1}\|Q\|_\infty
\\&\leq
2^nn!\|Q\|_\infty.
\end{split}

Each term in the product $\left|
\prod_{i=1}^{n} (\delta_{\sigma(i),i}+Q_{\sigma(i),i})
\right|$ above is at most $2$ in absolute value, and there is at least one $i$ so that $\delta_{\sigma(i),i}=0$, so the product is at most $2^{n-1}\|Q\|_\infty$ in absolute value.
The rest of the estimates are similar.

Comment: @Typhon thanks for your reply. But, I am confused about the terms there. Do you have a reference for where I can read about it? I couldn't find this form by doing a quick google search. though I did come across characteristic polynomials of a matrix. Is this the same thing?

Comment: $sgn(\sigma)$, I believe, is the sign function alternating between discrete values of $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: @Sentient hi -- yup, I did realize, but don't know what $\sigma$ here refers to in terms of the matrix $Q$

Comment: It refers to the index of the columns or row since you can compute the determinant through both. So for a $\mathbb{R}^{5x5}$ matrix, $\sigma$ would range from $1$ to $5$ discretely.

Comment: @Sentient So, for each $\sigma$ (row and col), one needs the product of some elements of the $Q$ matrix? Don't really see the point of the $\text{sgn}$ function though since it should just be positive. Pls do let me know if you may know of a reference for this. Also, any ideas about the other Q's would be much appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: @Typhon The [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) *can* be used as a definition - especially for people to be able to calculate them without needing to understand what they are - but "some guy thought it up" is a misleading perspective. Determinants measure signed volume in the case of reals, which for geometric reasons entails it is invariant under certain elementary row operations and subsequently is a multilinear, alternating function of its columns. By working it out by hand and noticing the pattern, we can induct to obtain Leibniz formula.

Comment: @Sentient and OP: $\sigma$ refers to any of the $5!=120$ possible permutations of the set $\{1,\cdots,5\}$.

Comment: @anon thank you so very much for this ref and also for the reference! I had no idea about this. So, the $\text{sign}$ fcn indeed makes sense here--it is negative for odds and positive for evens. Would really appreciate it of you can kindly shed some light on Q's 2) and 3) as well :) This question is linked to this one here --- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376054/satisfying-the-following-determinant-inequality -- if you look in the answer of the 5th observation, you would see $\det(W^{-1} + Z) = \det(W)^{-1} \det(I + WZ) = \det(W)^{-1} {\color{red} -} \det(W)^{-1} (\det(I + WZ)-1)$

Comment: and I believe that the last equality should be $\det(W)^{-1} {\color{red} +} \det(W)^{-1} (\det(I + WZ)-1)$ instead .... unless if $\det(I + WZ) > 1$ which I am not sure is true since while $W$ is symmetric positive definite, $Z$ doesn't need to be. So, that's why I needed a lower-bound as in my 3) question above since I need that $\det(\dots) \geq 1$ inequality satisfied. I realize its a long answer, but would appreciate your assistance on this part. I really believe that the other answer is pretty clever, but I am trying to make sure that there aren't any glitches. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, $w^{-1}d=w^{-1}\color{Red}{+}w^{-1}(d-1)$.

Comment: @anon Thanks! If you may have any inputs on sorting this out, then, kindly post an answer or even any advice as to how to move fwd would be sincerely appreciated. (I think that the other soln strategy works once $\det(I + WZ) > 1$, but I don't think this is the case. Even if it does, one requires $\det(W) \leq 1$, which is very restrictive for my purposes. )

Comment: Not really in the mood for (3) or the other inequality stuff, but I wrote about the basics.

Comment: Wikipedia! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant

Comment: @ZachTeitler Ahhh! thanks for this :) Pls do look at my other posts above....I would appreciate it if you can kindly provide any insights on how to proceed and any advice on 3) would be appreciate, i.e., if it may be needed.

Comment: An obvious improvement is $|\delta + q| \leq |\delta| + |q|$ rather than $|\delta + q| \leq 2$. (on the assumption that $q \leq 1$)

Comment: It's too late now, but I posit you'd get better results if you had separated your questions into at least two posts -- one about the origin of the identities, and one about the inequalities you're actually interested in.

Comment: @Typhon We didn't get to decide what the formula was - it *came from somewhere*, there is an explanation for why it is what it is and how it came about, and that explanation isn't "it's just defined that way" or "some guy thought it up." There is a difference between "someone made it up" and someone figured it out: the story of Harry Potter was made up, the formula for a determinant was something people figured out. OP was curious, and your original comment seems to shut down that curiosity.

Comment: There is also the extra layer of connecting the recursive definition via column expansion alluded to in your second comment and the direct formula of Leibniz in the OP. Presumably it is not immediately obvious to most students how to derive the Leibniz formula from the recursive definition, so there is something to show.

Comment: @Typhon There are some things one doesn't know and I had no idea that there was such a determinant formula ... I don't think this "shits down" anyone: I could have searched thoroughly, but I don't think its a problem to ask here too (helping one another is good) ... "anon" really explained it properly along with the geometric meaning so it was helpful for me and I am sure for many others that may come. anyways, thanks for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the story of my quest for the bounds. I put $\varepsilon=\|Q\|_\infty$ and  split the quest into two parts.

The first of them was for upper bounds for $\det(I+Q)-1$. Clearly, they follow from  upper bounds for $|\det(I+Q)|$. We have  $\|I+Q\|_\infty\le 1+\varepsilon$, so $|\det(I+Q)|\le (1+2\varepsilon+n\varepsilon^2)^{n/2}$, by [Hadamard’s inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_inequality#Alternate_forms_and_corollaries). Compare it with the bound $2^nn!\varepsilon$ which you have (as I guess, for $\varepsilon\le 1$). By Stirling’s formula, there exists a number $0<\theta<1$ such that $n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n e^{\frac \theta{12n}}$. Thus $2^nn!\varepsilon\simeq n^n(2/e)^n\varepsilon$, so Hadamard’s inequality based bound is better. On the other hand, it is almost tight for big $\varepsilon$ (and at least some $n$), because $|\det (1+\varepsilon H_n)|\simeq |\varepsilon H_n|=\varepsilon^nn^{n/2}$, where $H_n$ is a [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) of order $n$ (provided it exists for such $n$). In case when you are interested only in small $\varepsilon\le 1$, I conjectured that this lower bound can be improved. From the other hand, I looked for inequalities applicable to bounds for $|\det(I+Q)-1|$ in “Inequalities” by Edwin F. Beckenbach and Richard Bellman and “Introduction to matrix analysis” by the latter, and found none, besides already used  Hadamard’s inequality.

So I started the quest for lower bounds for $\det(I+Q)-1$. Of course, it is at least $-|\det(I+Q)|-1$, so we can apply here the upper bounds for  $|\det(I+Q)|$ from the first part of the quest. For big $\varepsilon$ the summand $-1$ is not essential, so we stop here.

Cleary, if $\det(I+Q)=0$ then we are done. So we may assume the converse. Then provided  $\det(I+Q)>0$ (so we put $\varepsilon<1$) we can bound it using the equlity $\det(I+Q)=1/\det (I+Q)^{-1}$, represent the matrix $(I+Q)^{-1}$ as $I+P$ with $\|P\|_\infty$ small and then apply use for $\det(I+P)$ the upper bounds from the first part of the quest.

For instance, for $\varepsilon<1/n$ the series $-Q+Q^2-Q^3\dots$ converges, and I guess we can put as $P$ its limit. In this case $$\|P\|_\infty\le \varepsilon+n\varepsilon^2+n^2\varepsilon^3+\dots=\frac\varepsilon{1-n\varepsilon} .$$

An other, straightforward way to bound $\det (I+Q)^{-1}$ using the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $I+Q$, but this way is complicate, uses the inductive bounds for minors, and I guess that finally it’ll give a weak bound.

But I came to idea to use bounds following from Gauss elimination method for solving systems of linear equations, which looked much more promising.

But at this point I decided to google and found relevant results, which already were partially overlapping with mine. Namely, I found a paper “Note  on  best  possible  bounds  for  determinants of matrices  close  to  the  identity matrix” [BOS2] by Richard P. Brent, Judy-anne H. Osborn, and Warren D. Smith.

My prize was that bound $\det(I+Q)\ge 1−n\varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon<1/n$ is known from Ostrowski’s paper from 1938.  Bounds based on Gauss elimination method are worse. This is not so surprising,  because Ostrowski’s bound is best-possible, as it is attained if $Q =-\varepsilon J$, where $J$ is the $n\times n$ matrix of all ones.

On the other hand, as it sometimes happens in a life of a professional mathematician, the upper bound $|\det(I+Q)|\le (1+2\varepsilon+n\varepsilon^2)^{n/2}$ was already proven (two years ago by the same way) in Theorem 2 of [BOS2]. The authors also remarked that this bound is  best-possible  if  a  [skew-Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix#Skew_Hadamard_matrices) $H$ of order $n$ exists. To  see  this,  consider $I+Q=(1 + \varepsilon)I + \varepsilon(H − I)$. Such a matrix exists for $n =1, 2$, all multiples of four up to and including $4\times × 68$, as well as infinitely many larger $n$, such as all powers of two, see [CD]. Sharp bounds for small orders for which a skew-Hadamard matrix does not exist (e.g. $n=3$) are considered in [BOS1, §4.1].

*References*

[BOS1] Richard P. Brent, Judy-anne H. Osborn, Warren D. Smith, [Bounds on determinants of perturbed diagonal matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7084),  arXiv:1401.7048v7, 2014.

[BOS2] Richard P. Brent, Judy-anne H. Osborn, Warren D. Smith, *[Note  on  best  possible  bounds  for  determinants of matrices  close  to  the  identity matrix](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/rpb258-LAA.pdf)*, Linear Algebra and its Applications, **466** (2015), 21–26.

[CD] C.J. Colbourn, J.H. Dinitz, *Handbook of Combinatorial Designs*, 2nd edition, CRC Press, New York, 2006.

[O] A.M. Ostrowski, *Sur l’approximation du déterminant de Fredholm par  les déterminants des systèmes d’equations linéaires*, Ark. Math. Stockholm Ser. A, **26** (1938), 1–15.

Comment: Hi -- many thanks for the references! I read BOS2 a bit and was just wondering whether or not the upper bound held only for small $\epsilon = \| Q \|_\infty $ or doesn't matter? Also, if have that $Q = AB$, then, can the above be simplified -- I know that $\| AB \|_\infty \leq \| A \| \| B \|$ ... I am just wondering how the upper bound can be simplified since there is that power $\frac{n}{2}$. Thank you again and please take a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2387250/recursive-relation-and-inequality if you may have a chance. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: @user2457324 The upper bound is derived from Hadamard’s inequality. It holds for each $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: I didn't got the next question (about $Q=AB$). Also, why this case is easier? For instance, when $B=I$, we have $Q=A$ and have the same problem for $A$, isn’t it?

Comment: Thanks for the first one. Not saying it is easier, but just was wondering how to expand the upper bound for when $Q = AB$:
$| \det (I + AB) | \leq  (1 + 2 \| AB \|_\infty + n \| AB \|_\infty^2 )^{\frac{n}{2}} $
but not sure how to upper bound the expression above using the induced norm and sub-multiplicative property. Would appreciate any assistance on doing that.

Comment: @user2457324 I think that without additional restrictions on $A$ and $B$, giving restrictions on $Q$, decomposition $Q=AB$ doesn’t help to strengthen the upper bound.

Answer (score 5):

(1) $\sigma$ ranges over elements of $S_n$, i.e. permutations of $\{1,\cdots,n\}$, and $\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)$ refers to the *sign* of the permutation ($+1$ if it is an even permutation, $-1$ if it is an odd permutation). Geometrically, permutations of coordinates are preserve or reverse the orientation of space exactly when the sign of the permutation is positive of negative.

Let's work this out by hand with $n=3$. In *one-line notation* for permutations, here are all of the $3!=6$ permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$ and their signs:

$$ \begin{array}{ccc} \color{Red}{(123),+} & \color{Lime}{(132),-} & \color{Blue}{(213),-} \\ (231),+ & (312),+ & (321),- \end{array} $$

Therefore, we have (using the above permutations in this order)

$$ \large \det\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{array}{l} \color{Red}{+}a_{\color{Red}{1}1}a_{\color{Red}{2}2}a_{\color{Red}{3}3} \color{Lime}{-}a_{\color{Lime}{1}1}a_{\color{Lime}{3}2}a_{\color{Lime}{2}3}\color{Blue}{-}a_{\color{Blue}{2}1}a_{\color{Blue}{1}2}a_{\color{Blue}{3}3} \\ +a_{21}a_{32}a_{13}+a_{31}a_{12}a_{23}-a_{31}a_{22}a_{13}. \end{array}  $$

(Sorry for lime green's harshness, normal green is too close to black.)

(2) The entries of the identity matrix $I$ are the Kronecker delta function $\delta_{ij}$ (which is $1$ when $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise). The sum over all permutations can be split into two: the term when $\sigma=\mathrm{id}$ is the identity map, and all of the other terms when $\sigma\ne \mathrm{id}$. In the first case, $\mathrm{id}(i)=i$ for all $i$ and $\mathrm{sgn}(\mathrm{id})=+1$ so the summand is $+\prod_{i=1}^n (1+Q_{ii})$.

Comment: thanks so very much for this! I would really appreciate it if you can look at the inequality part at your earliest convenience. But, for now, do you think that finding the lower bound is the right intuition to go about satisfying that determinant inequality? Also, I would really like to avoid $\det(W) \leq 1$. Pls do take a look at this...it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Also, a quick question so I feel comfortable--if $W$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix, and $Z$ is just a symmetric matrix, then, this doesn't imply that $\det(I + WZ) \geq 1$ correct?

Comment: Nope it doesn't, e.g. $W=[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}]$ and $Z=[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}]$.